# Python Regular Expression with optional but greedy groups

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to write a regular expression to match a string that may or may not contain two tags. I need the expression to return me all five elements of the string, depending on whether they exist, but when I make the tags optional, the wildcard bits seem to gobble them up:

Inputs could be:

```
text{a}more{b}words  
{a}text{b}test  
text  
text{b}text  
text{b}  
text{a}text
```

Et cetera. The only thing guaranteed is that `<a>` will always be before `<b>`, provided they exist.

My expression now looks as follows:

```
^(.*?)(\{a\})?(.*?)(\{b\})?(.*?)$
```

Unfortunately, this ends up throwing all text into the last group, regardless of whether or not the tags are present. Is there some way to make them greedy, yet keep them optional? `re.findall` doesn't seem to help either unfortunately.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! :)

Comment: For starters, you don't need to escape curly brackets.

Comment: There are only conditionnal basic RE in your general RE: (.*?) with * and ? , then optional (\{a\}) , then again conditional and again and again. That is to say , there is no anchor , apart the ^ and $ symbols. A regex can't works well without at least some parts that capture a stable environnment around the variable parts of a string.

Comment: Thanks. Posted a vague solution below (with escaped brackets), but got rid of them now...

Comment: Are **text{a}more{b}words** a string to analyze, **{a}text{b}test** another string to analyze, and so forth ? That is to say , the text to match isn't **text{a}more{b}words {a}text{b}test text text{b}text text{b} text{a}text** , is it ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the following regex: `^(.*(?={a})|.*?)({a})?(.*(?={b})|.*)({b})?(.*?)$`

```
import re

inputs = ['{a}text{b}test', 'text', 'text{b}text', 'text{b}', 'text{a}text']
p = re.compile(r"^(.*(?={a})|.*?)({a})?(.*(?={b})|.*)({b})?(.*?)$")
for input in inputs:
    print p.match(input).groups()
```

Output:

```
('', '{a}', 'text', '{b}', 'test')
('', None, 'text', None, '')
('', None, 'text', '{b}', 'text')
('', None, 'text', '{b}', '')
('text', '{a}', 'text', None, '')
```

Comment: this is pretty cool - thanks! (the other answers worked, too, but this one is quite elegant)

Answer (score 0):

I found one solution, which seems to work. Not very pretty, though:

```
^((?P<b1>.*)(?P<o1>\{start\})(?P<m1>.*)(?P<c1>\{end\})(?P<e1>.*))|((?P<b2>.*)(?P<c2>\{end\})(?P<e2>.*))|((?P<b3>.*)(?P<o3>\{start\})(?P<e3>.*))$
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this gets the output you want, but:

```
import re

inputs = ['text{a}more{b}words',
'{a}text{b}test',
'text',
'text{b}text',
'text{b}',
'text{a}text']

pattern = re.compile(r'^([^{]*)(\{a\})?([^{]*)(\{b\})?([^{]*)$')

for inpt in inputs:
    match = pattern.match(inpt)
    if match:
        print match.groups()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `split` to break the string into pieces and make it more manageable. By placing your split pattern in parenthesis, it is included in the result.

```
>>> import re
>>> re.split("({[a|b]})","text{a}more{b}words")
['text', '{a}', 'more', '{b}', 'words']
>>> re.split("({[a|b]})", "{a}more{b}words")
['', '{a}', 'more', '{b}', 'words']
```

The one thing to note is that an empty string will be present when your tag exists, but there is nothing before/after it.

Answer (score 0):

I had found a RE

```
RE1 = ("^"
       "((?:(?!{a}|{b}).)+|)"
       "({a})?"
       "((?:(?!{b}).)+|)"
       "({b})?"
       "(.*)")
```

It's the same principle as, but is less good than, the RE of Andrew.

Thinking about these solutions, I found another, that seems clearer to me:

```
RE2 = ("^"
       "(.+(?={a}))?"
       "({a})?"
       "(.+(?={b}))?"
       "({b})?"
       "(.*)"
       "$")
```

I compared

```
import re

REA = ("^"
       "(.*(?={a})|.*?)"
       "({a})?"
       "(.*(?={b})|.*)"
       "({b})?"
       "(.*?)"
       "$")    # Andrew's RE
patA = re.compile(REA)


RE1 = ("^"
       "((?:(?!{a}|{b}).)+|)"
       "({a})?"
       "((?:(?!{b}).)+|)"
       "({b})?"
       "(.*)")
pat1 = re.compile(RE1)


RE2 = ("^"
       "(.+(?={a}))?"
       "({a})?"
       "(.+(?={b}))?"
       "({b})?"
       "(.*)")
pat2 = re.compile(RE2)


for ch in ( "ante{a}medium{b}post",
            "ante{a}medium{b}","{a}medium{b}post","ante{a}{b}post",
            "ante{a}text","{a}medium{b}","text{b}post",
            "ante{a}{b}","{a}{b}post",
            "ante{a}","{a}text","text{b}","{b}post","{a}{b}",
            "{a}","{b}","text",):
    print ch
    print patA.search(ch).groups("")
    print pat1.search(ch).groups("")
    print pat2.search(ch).groups("")
    print
```

result

```
ante{a}medium{b}post
('ante', '{a}', 'medium', '{b}', 'post')
('ante', '{a}', 'medium', '{b}', 'post')
('ante', '{a}', 'medium', '{b}', 'post')

ante{a}medium{b}
('ante', '{a}', 'medium', '{b}', '')
('ante', '{a}', 'medium', '{b}', '')
('ante', '{a}', 'medium', '{b}', '')

{a}medium{b}post
('', '{a}', 'medium', '{b}', 'post')
('', '{a}', 'medium', '{b}', 'post')
('', '{a}', 'medium', '{b}', 'post')

ante{a}{b}post
('ante', '{a}', '', '{b}', 'post')
('ante', '{a}', '', '{b}', 'post')
('ante', '{a}', '', '{b}', 'post')

ante{a}text
('ante', '{a}', 'text', '', '')
('ante', '{a}', 'text', '', '')
('ante', '{a}', '', '', 'text')

{a}medium{b}
('', '{a}', 'medium', '{b}', '')
('', '{a}', 'medium', '{b}', '')
('', '{a}', 'medium', '{b}', '')

text{b}post
('', '', 'text', '{b}', 'post')
('text', '', '', '{b}', 'post')
('', '', 'text', '{b}', 'post')

ante{a}{b}
('ante', '{a}', '', '{b}', '')
('ante', '{a}', '', '{b}', '')
('ante', '{a}', '', '{b}', '')

{a}{b}post
('', '{a}', '', '{b}', 'post')
('', '{a}', '', '{b}', 'post')
('', '{a}', '', '{b}', 'post')

ante{a}
('ante', '{a}', '', '', '')
('ante', '{a}', '', '', '')
('ante', '{a}', '', '', '')

{a}text
('', '{a}', 'text', '', '')
('', '{a}', 'text', '', '')
('', '{a}', '', '', 'text')

text{b}
('', '', 'text', '{b}', '')
('text', '', '', '{b}', '')
('', '', 'text', '{b}', '')

{b}post
('', '', '', '{b}', 'post')
('', '', '', '{b}', 'post')
('', '', '', '{b}', 'post')

{a}{b}
('', '{a}', '', '{b}', '')
('', '{a}', '', '{b}', '')
('', '{a}', '', '{b}', '')

{a}
('', '{a}', '', '', '')
('', '{a}', '', '', '')
('', '{a}', '', '', '')

{b}
('', '', '', '{b}', '')
('', '', '', '{b}', '')
('', '', '', '{b}', '')

text
('', '', 'text', '', '')
('text', '', '', '', '')
('', '', '', '', 'text')
```

There are some few differences, but the 3 solutions work fine.